# Do all universal mapping properties induce an isomorphism?

Tags: category-theory

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQYjekxqw-Q&t=1601s), the lecturer said "Any two terminal objects are isomorphic, because it [terminal object-ness] is a universal mapping property".

Is it true that all "universal mapping properties" induce an isomorphism? i.e. if objects $A,B$ both have universal mapping property $P$, then $A,B$ are isomorphic? If so, why?

Comment: This is indeed always true where I've encountered it. There might be a suitable metatheorem somewhere. It's a useful guideline.

Comment: well, you get two unique morphisms going both ways, which by the universal property induce the identity on the diagram, in particular, the identity would be such a morphism, but by uniqueness, the composition of those two must be the identity . Now since you can argue this both ways the induced morphism must be an iso. However, you actually get something a lot stronger, you get unique up to UNIQUE iso. (the lacking of this uniqueness is what fucks up triangulated categories as if those have functorial cones (i.e. unique up to unique is, and not just iso) the category would be abelian)

Comment: also please forgive me, but since the detials of this argument can become quite cumbersome, I out it as a sketch in the argument, however if this suffices for you, I am happy to write it as an answer as well

Comment: This is the Yoneda lemma essentially; which tells you that if $\hom(-, A)\simeq \hom(-,B)$, then $A\simeq B$. Indeed a universal problem is essentially a functor $F:C\to \mathbf{Set}$, and an object satisfying the associated universal mapping property is simply a representative of the functor. Two representatives of a same functor are uniquely isomorphic (uniqueness of an isomorphism respecting the representing data)

Comment: Note that it turns out that you can prove this part of the Yoneda lemma by proving that terminal objects are unique up to unique isomorphism : early CT is a lot like that : many results follow from one another, and so its always a bit hard picking which one you prove first and so on - but at this point to state the result you're mentioning, the best way is this corollary of the Yoneda lemma